# Configuring Logback in Eclipse

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm in the process of switching from Log4j to Logback but I'm not having success at making Logback work yet. I have placed `logback.xml` in the root directory of my Eclipse Java project and below is its content:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myApp.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

And below is the relevant content of my `Main.java`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class Main
{
  static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    logger.info("Main started");
  }
}
```

This does not seem to be working as no file named `myApp.log` is created in the root of my Eclipse Java application. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The configuration file needs to be on the classpath. My guess is that it isn't. Check the build path for the project.

Comment: For maven it helps moving the file to **src/main/resources** following this [advice](http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/Project-Can-t-Find-logback-xml-file-td3442.html)

Comment: Also, by "on the classpath", that means the *directory* (path) to the file is on the classpath.  E.g.: `CLASSPATH="/foo:/goo:/foo/bar"` will find the file `/foo/bar/logback.xml` on the classpath.