# Configuring Logback with sl4j in Eclipse Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, slf4j, logback

I have a eclipse maven project in which I am trying to use `logback.xml`. But the `logback.xml` is not getting picked. I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085260/configuring-logback-in-eclipse) and have verified that `logback.xml` is placed in `src/main/resources/` & it is in my classpath.

My `logback.xml` looks like below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern> 
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- Daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>/tmp/SolrUpdater.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- Keep 7 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Maven dependencies looks like below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have also verified that `src/main/resource` is marked as resource directory in eclipse as shown below:-
[image]

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use two logging backends at the same time. You should be seeing a runtime warning about multiple SLF4J implementations on the classpath.

`slf4j-jdk14` precedes `logback-classic` in your dependency list, so all log messages get routed to the `java.util.logging` backend, and your Logback configuration has no effect at all.

Remove the `slf4j-jdk14` dependency and make sure you don't have any other SLF4J backends as transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably src/main/resources has not been recognized as a resource directory by eclipse and need some refresh or action to do that.

Do you check that this directory is marked as resource directory in project configuration ?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question to include the details.